# how to make a day populate html elements in from current day to a week in advance?

Tags: javascript

I have this function that I am working on, but it's not working as it should, I want the .currentday html class which is li and have a total number of 7 (7 days) to populate in this pattern

the current day , and a 6 days after it so if today is Friday it should populate
fri, sat, sun ... Thursday. and stop at the Thursday day. any ideas thank.

```js
function Dynamicday() {
    var d = new Date();
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";

    let n = weekday[d.getDay()];

    let Dynamicday = document.querySelectorAll('.currentday');

    for (var z = 0; z < Dynamicday.length; z++) {
        Dynamicday[z].innerHTML = n;
    }

    console.log(Dynamicday);
}

Dynamicday();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
let n = d.getDay();
for (let z = 0; z < Dynamicday.length; z++) {
    Dynamicday[z].innerHTML = weekday[n++ % 7];
}
```

Increment `n` each time and then modulus by 7 to get the day index.
See it run [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ym9srqoz/).